# IoT Hub service SDK get Edge runtime response

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk, azure-sdk

According to the documentation [Understand the Azure IoT Edge runtime and its architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime), the edge agent module should send runtime response:

```
The IoT Edge agent sends runtime response to IoT Hub. Here is a list of possible responses:
200 - OK
400 - The deployment configuration is malformed or invalid.
417 - The device doesn't have a deployment configuration set.
412 - The schema version in the deployment configuration is invalid.
406 - The IoT Edge device is offline or not sending status reports.
500 - An error occurred in the IoT Edge runtime.
```

How can I fetch the current state via the SDK? I'm afraid that there's no method in the Node.js SDK for this info. Is it even possible?

In the Azure portal the current state is visible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If are you using the [Azure IoT **service** SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/tree/master/service), you should be able to retrieve IoT Edge Device status. See also how to [Monitor module twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-monitor-module-twins)

"Module twins in Azure IoT Hub enable monitoring the connectivity and health of your IoT Edge deployments. Module twins store useful information in your IoT hub about the performance of your running modules. The IoT Edge agent and the IoT Edge hub runtime modules each maintain their module twins, $edgeAgent and $edgeHub, respectively"

"exitCode" and "runtimeStatus" properties should show you the error, can you see it there?

Comment: Actually, I was searching for the "Runtime response" of the device which is shown in the Azure portal. I think it's the "lastDesiredStatus" object at the beginning of the reported properties object - at least I can find the same codes there as mentioned in my question.
The "runtimeStatus" is part of the module properties and seems to be wrong, the Edge device is offline for days and a few modules are still considered as "running".

Don't know why it's called "lastDesiredStatus" - for me it's the "lastReportedStatus".

Comment: @AndreasSulzermeier yes the naming "lastDesiredStatus" looks confusing as it is inside reported properties object... On the "runtimeStatus" can you consistently reproduce the situation that edge is offline but still reporting "running" ? If so can you report a bug on [iotedge github repo](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues)? When doing so, refer this SO thread as well as tag me 'asergaz'